# Realm database getGlobalInstanceCount() and getLocalInstanceCount() getting increasing until kill the application

Tags: android, kotlin, realm, realm-mobile-platform

Realm database GlobalInstanceCount and LocalInstanceCount goes on increasing until kill the application. Bcz of this facing out of memory error . Our application using many insert and update operation in both main thread and background thread. But after once work is finishes doing close() realm instances successfully. In spite of close in the both main thread and background thread also global and local count not getting reducing. Please help me thank you in advance.

```
var locCount = Realm.getLocalInstanceCount(Realm.getDefaultConfiguration())
var globalCount = Realm.getGlobalInstanceCount(Realm.getDefaultConfiguration())
Log.d("LogCount","Global Count= $globalCount , Local Count= $locCount")
```

Below singleton class using for each database operations. That is same instance using for all the operation not creating new instance.

```
  object RealMDatabase {

    fun getRealm(): Realm {
        return if (Looper.getMainLooper().thread == Thread.currentThread()) {
            if (!::realm_main.isInitialized || realm_main.isClosed) {
                realm_main = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
            }
            realm_main

        } else {
            if (!::realm_io.isInitialized || realm_io.isClosed) {
                realm_io = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
            }
            realm_io
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: What's your current output? Why do you add `"tin"=>"$tin",` if that's not in your expected output? And I think your `implode` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: my current output is like {"tin":"S4243534" ,"seatsToCancel":["U23/",/"L43/",/"U12"]}  but  in post method this is not working.Getting json parser error.

Comment: Can you please add that code in your question, not in the comments? Thanks. That's because your `implode` is wrong, no need to add `"`, this will be handled by `json_encode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm guessing that your seats to cancel are coming in as a comma-separated list from the URL. So all you need to do is `explode()` the `GET` parameter to turn it into an array, place it as the value to a `key` and `json_encode()` it.

i.e.

```
$seatsToCancel = explode(',', $_GET['seatsToCancel']);
$params = [
    'tin' => $tin,
    'seatsToCancel' => $seatsToCancel,
];
$paramsJson = json_encode($params);
```

That should get you the result you're after:

```
{"tin":"S4243534" ,"seatsToCancel":["U23","L43","U12"]}
```

You may want to consider what happens if the `GET` parameter is empty and whether or not you want any additional error checking.

Comment: Not sure how you expect this to even work when you have a `;` after the json_encode. Even if that is removed you still don't get the correct output. https://3v4l.org/0kHJl

Comment: @ViruMH How can this work fine? You got some syntax error resistant code?

Comment: Danke for the spot on the additional `;`, mistake on my part leaving that in @Andreas - Just needed to move the encode to encode everything. Early morning mistake. Here you got bud: https://3v4l.org/CPmac

Answer (score 1):

I assume your `$seatArray` is `["U23","L43","U12"]`?
In that case you can do like this:

```
$seatArray = ["U23","L43","U12"];

$finalarray = ["tin"=>$tin,"seatsToCancel" => $seatArray];

echo json_encode($finalarray); //{"tin":"S4243534","seatsToCancel":["U23","L43","U12"]}
```

Edited to add the new requirement from edited question